# Slides on different levels in Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, slideshow

I was wondering if Beamer allows to nest slides in both horizontal and vertical directions. So that, during a presentation, we move to different "levels" by pressing the vertical and horizontal arrow keys.

To be more precise, I'm asking for something similar to the "Vertical Slides" feature of [Slides.com](https://slides.com/features).

Any comment is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible using the arrow keys. However, you can add hyperlinks that point to a subset of slides at the end of the presentation. These slides will then be skipped unless you follow the hyperlink. You can therefore decide to show or not show them during your talk.

Comment: @leandriis: thanks! Yes, I know that it is possible to use hyperlinks, but I was wondering if there is an alternative, quick way using arrow keys only.